# node-printer not printing in net printer (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing

I'm trying to send directly documents to my printer. I have used node-printer and have not error, but printer is not receiving anything. This is my code:

```
var printer = require("printer");
    filename = process.argv[2] || __filename;

console.log('platform:', process.platform);
console.log('default printer name: ' + (printer.getDefaultPrinterName() || 'is not defined on your computer'));
console.log('try to print file: ' + filename);

if( process.platform != 'win32') {
    printer.printFile({filename:filename,
    printer: process.env[3], 
    success:function(jobID){
       console.log("sent to printer with ID: "+jobID);
    },
    error:function(err){
       console.log(err);
    }
});

} else {
  var fs = require('fs');
  printer.printDirect({
    data:fs.readFileSync(filename).toString(),
    printer: process.env[3], 
    type: 'RAW',
    success:function(jobID){
      console.log("sent to printer with ID: "+jobID);
    },
    error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I test do "node print.js lorem.txt" and it looks like document is sent to print queue, but net printer is not receiving anything.

By the way, I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: So can we assume that printing from, say, Notepad.exe works? Because if the document appears in the queue but isn't printed, it doesn't sound like the issue is with the code.

Comment: Yes, of course. Notepad.exe is working properly.

Comment: What file are you trying to print?

Comment: It was to print pdf (recipes and invoces) :)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the printer with `printer: process.env[3]` but looks like you want to use the default printer because you are writing `printer.getDefaultPrinterName()` to console, so please try removing `printer: process.env[3],` and make the module to print in the default printer and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I have tried with your proposal with the same result.